# SQL Table MAX Limit

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm building a web application that uses database (MySQL in particular).
For each database, each user will have their own table, that each has their category. For example:

Database 1 (Music Playlist) - Tables:User1,User2,User3

Database 2 (Wall posts) - Tables:User1,User2,User3

Database 3 (Wall replies) - Tables:User1_post1,User1_post2,User3_post1

Let's say I have 100,000 users now. Thinking about how many tables there are in total, will this be wise? Is there a maximum table limit to this? Will this affect performance?

I'm taking a course right now and I just realized there is JOINing of tables. Is this a better idea? Will it have a difference in performance?

Comment: There is a name for this model (actually: 2 names, but 1 is inpolite): Hierarchical data model. Advice is not to use this: Way too much maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Relational databases are designed to handle large amounts of data.  Tables with many millions of rows are not uncommon; there are examples with billions of rows as well.  So, you don't have to worry about 100,000 users, as long as you understand how to structure your database.  Two key ideas are indexes and partitions.

You do have a problem with your structure, however.  You do *not* want a separate table for each user.  You want a single table with a column specifying the user.  Although the tables will have hundreds of thousands or millions of rows, you do not need to worry.  Databases are designed for this type of volume.